# Behavior object is not working properly in Angular 2

Tags: angular

**Service** SharedService

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  public userData: BehaviorSubject<IUserData> = new BehaviorSubject<IUserData>({
        /*user: <IUserVM>{
            identityId: '-',
            imgSrc: 'public/assets/img/user_sm.png',
            name: '-'
        },*/
        accountList: [],
        selectedAccount: <IAccountVM>{}
        //sessionValid: false
    });

    updateUserData(data: IUserData){
        this.userData.next(data);

    }


    public toggleSidebar: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    updateToggleSidebar(data: boolean){
        this.toggleSidebar.next(data);
    }

}
```

this service is used to share and update the data

**app.component.html**

```
      <li *ngFor="let item of membershipList" (click)="switchAcc(item);" [ngClass]="{'active': item.id === selectedAccount.id}">
                    <a><img [src]="item.imageUrl"  id="{{item.id}}"></a>
                </li>
                <li><button class="btn btn btn-quiet-outline add-team-btn"> + </button></li>
            </ul>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
switchAcc(item?: IMembership) {
    //  this.sharedService.userData.value.selectedAccount = item;
    var userData = {
        "accountList": this.membershipList,
        "selectedAccount": item
    };
    this.sharedService.updateUserData(userData);
    console.log("userData", userData);
    if (item.type.toLowerCase() == 'personal') {

        this.router.navigate(['/app/teams/' +item.id + '/dashboard/personal']);
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/app/teams/' + item.id + '/dashboard/business']);
    }
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');

}
```

**business.dashboard.component.ts**

```
constructor(public sharedService: SharedService, private activateroute: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.sharedService.userData.subscribe(value => {
        console.log("value",value)
        this.selectedAccount = value.selectedAccount;
        this.accountList = value.accountList;
        console.log("selectedAccount",value.selectedAccount.name);
    });
}
```

`business.dashboard.component.ts` is the page where i try to get the updated value but value get updated but it does not reflect in HTML when i try to console (this.selectdaccount) it retain the prevoius value not updated value

And when i double click on link `app.component.html` it working perfect i think problem in first it get updated and then listen to the updated value

Comment: Where do you provide your `SharedService` to your components?

Comment: in shared folder service but switchAcc is a function which access the sharedservice and updated data..

Comment: Can you share the code where you provide this service and can you add the @Component annotations of your components?

Comment: yes everything is ok..value gets updated but when i try to render it does not take updated value render old value .and when i double click on link then render updated value

Comment: Ok so `this.selectedAccount` gets updated inside the subscribe but html doesn't get updated right? Have you tried triggering change detection manually?

Answer (score 2):

Try triggering change detection manually

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'

@Component({...})
export class ..
    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, public sharedService: SharedService, private activateroute: ActivatedRoute ){..}

    this.sharedService.userData.subscribe(value => {
        console.log("value",value)
        this.selectedAccount = value.selectedAccount;
        this.accountList = value.accountList;
        console.log("selectedAccount",value.selectedAccount.name);
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
```

Comment: thanx @echonax ..actually i found that error because another component was being updated the value so result in conflict so it gets first updated value not second updated value..solution was to prevent updating from another component and ensure only one component will update the value and other are just listen to that value

Comment: @UmeshShende ah glad you figured it out :-) you can answer your own question and accept it as the answer to close the issue.